# SAP RAP ABAP : Navigate across business objects/CDS Root View Entities

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, cds, rap

I have a managed RAP development with 2 root view entities having their own IAM apps. These 2 root view entities have a many-to-many relationship. This means that there are there are many instances of Root View Entity A associated to a single instance of Root View Entity B, and vice versa.

Now the requirement is to provide links of all associated Root View Entity A on the object page of every instance of Root View Entity B similar to line item table or child table, such that on clicking any link, the corresponding object page of the clicked instance of Root View Entity A is opened, and vice versa with the links to all associated Root View Entity B instances on the Object page of Root View Entity A.

Any suggestions for the same?

Thanks and Regards,